# Scroll whole screen height (watchOS)

Tags: swift, watchos

I want to make interface be scrollable like in Health app, on the full screen height, and do not allow to stop scrolling in the middle, is it possible?

For example, I have two buttons, and I want them be visible one on screen, another will shown after scrolling. And the main part, is that if scroll started, it will continue by itself until the second button would stand in the center of the screen, and the first button will hide..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is no any possibility to make padded scrolls, looks like apple used for it closed API..

As for me, worked chose to use dummy picker and animate changing (hiding and uhhiding) of WKInterfaceGroups, whose height equals to screen height by rolling digital crown)